# Export KDE settings between different machines

Tags: kde, configuration, kde5

KDE version: Plasma 5.6

How can I export the settings of KDE from one machine to another? I am referring to all the KDE application settings, shortcuts, konsole theme settings etc... I am using Kubuntu 16.04.